# Can I call data-bs-target after response data is true?

Tags: vuejs3

'My vue code like this :'

```
<teleport to="body">
  <div v-show="success" id="msgModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-light">
          <h5 class="modal-title">applyed successed!</h5>
          <button type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <font-awesome-icon icon="times" />
          </button>
        </div
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</teleport>

<script>
   function callBackEndFunc(){

   if(condition){
     api.apiMethod1({})
         .then(() => {
          alert("success!");
         //want to call  data-bs-target="#msgModal"
       });
   }
}
</script>
```

When callBackEndFunc was called and after ajax success
want to want to call  data-bs-target="#msgModal" to show div message in #msgModal.

Can anyone give me some advisor how to solve this problem?

Comment: Where is `data-bs-target`? Can't you set a state on it and update it?

Comment: @kissu  If data-bs-target set on a button click, and once button clicked data-bs-target will show up like a div content.  I have no idea how to change state or update on it.


The link below is like a jqury using way 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62745610/how-can-i-intercept-the-bootstrap-data-target-event

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.